# Supermicro X10DRL-i 4 Beeps while Running GPU Stress Test

Tags: supermicro, stress-testing

As a bit of a testbench before deployment, I'm running a Supermicro X10DRL-i w/ dual Xeon E5-2620v4's and 64GB RAM. I have a Sapphire AMD Vega56 in the 16x slot.

I was running some stress tests today to check for system stability and I ran into an issue with Furmark on Win10 with the GPU passes through and a slight overclock applied. The system appeared to run fine, but occasionally, the motherboard would make 4 beeps in rapid succession, a similar beep pattern to when doing an IPMI-based reset.

I can't seem to find any errors in either the Windows or IPMI event log and the system appeared otherwise stable, even for those beeps. Turning off the Furmark stress test stopped those beeps from happening, but it seems weird that it could even cause something like that.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be some temperature alarm or power alarm, but I can't seem to find any indication of that in the motherboard manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the motherboard. The fan controller was throwing temperature alerts.